# Problemas con el orden de ejecución y guardado de datos en JavaScript con TypeOrm y NestJs

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos, nestjs, typeorm

Estoy tratando de guardar registros en una base de datos, sin embargo he notado que no esta funcionando como esperaba.

Cuento con el siguiente `array`:

```
   const rows = [{
    'DIRECCION': 'UNIDAD DE TECNOLOGIAS OPERACIONALES Y DE INFORMACION',
    'ÁREA': 'DIRECCION EJECUTIVA DE TECNOLOGIAS OPERACIONALES',
    'CONTRATO Y/O CONCEPTO': 'OFICIO',
    'CARPETA 1': 2017,
    'CARPETA 2': 'N/A',
    'CARPETA 3': 'N/A',
    'CARPETA 4': 'N/A',
    'CARPETA 5': 'N/A',
    'NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO': 'File_Oficio_2017.pdf',
    'NUMERO DE IMÁGENES': 2
   }, {
    'DIRECCION': 'UNIDAD DE TECNOLOGIAS OPERACIONALES Y DE INFORMACION',
    'ÁREA': 'DIRECCION EJECUTIVA DE TECNOLOGIAS OPERACIONALES',
    'CONTRATO Y/O CONCEPTO': 'OFICIO',
    'CARPETA 1': 2017,
    'CARPETA 2': 'N/A',
    'CARPETA 3': 'N/A',
    'CARPETA 4': 'N/A',
    'CARPETA 5': 'N/A',
    'NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO': 'File_2017.pdf',
    'NUMERO DE IMÁGENES': 22
   }]
```

Lo que busco es obtener los `keys` del objeto y registrarlos en una tabla dentro de una base de datos. Para ello itero el `array` de objetos `obj` y en cada iteración obtengo:

```
rows.forEach(async (item, index) => {
   const data = Object.keys(el); // Donde `el` representa el elemento de la iteración.
   // data =
   // ['DIRECCION','ÁREA','CONTRATO Y/O CONCEPTO',
   // 'CARPETA 1','CARPETA 2','CARPETA 3', 'CARPETA 4','CARPETA 5',
   // 'NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO','NUMERO DE IMÁGENES']
   ...
}
```

Utilizo un `forEach` para recorrer el array con las `keys`

```
    data.forEach(async (item) => {
        const idsHeader = [];
        const exist: Header = await this.headerService.findBy({
          key: 'name',
          value: item,
        });
        if (!exist) {
          const res = await this.headerService.createHeader({
            name: item,
          });
        }
      });
```

La función `findBy()` y `createHeader()` funcionan, sin embargo he notado que el `forEach` no esta ejecutando las llamadas a buscar o guardar los datos correctamente:

función `findBy()`

```
 public async findBy({
    key,
    value,
  }: {
    key: keyof CreateHeaderDto; // cuenta con el dato name: string
    value: any;
  }): Promise<Header> {
    try {
      console.log('Buscando Header', value); // Log para analizar la ejecución
      const header: Header = await this.headerRepository
        .createQueryBuilder('header')
        .where({ [key]: value })
        .getOne();
      return header;
    } catch (error) {
      throw ErrorManager.createSignatureError(error.message);
    }
  }
```

función `createHeader()`

```
public async createHeader(body: CreateHeaderDto): Promise<Header> {
    try {
      console.log('Creando Header', body.name); // Log para analizar la ejecución
      return await this.headerRepository.save(body);
    } catch (error) {
      throw ErrorManager.createSignatureError(error.message);
    }
  }
```

Ambas funciones se ejecutan la acción, respectivamente. Al hacer la ejecución, con la tabla de la base de datos vacía, observo el comportamiento de los `log`, en cada función, y el guardado de los datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en tabla los registros se guardan de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se observa que no se registran ordenadamente y que las búsqueda (`findBy()`), para saber si ya existe el registro, no esta encontrando el registro en la tabla. Lo que me lleva a pensar, basado en los `logs`, que `TypeOrm` o el código, esta guardando los registros hasta que se termina de recorrer el `array` de datos, por ello no se encuentran datos existentes al momento de hacer la búsqueda.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que todo se ejecute de manera ordenada y los datos se guarden ordenados, como esta dentro del `array`